# Solution of $2{{I}_{xy}}={{I}_{x}}+{{I}_{y}}$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How i can find  the general solution of the following partial differential equation:

$$\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}I}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial I}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial I}{\partial y} \right)$$
I made a guess $I\left( x,y \right)={{e}^{x+y}}$

Comment: $ce^{x+y}$ is indeed a set of solutions to your PDE.

Comment: Try separation of variables $I = X(x)Y(y)$ and $I=X(x) + Y(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\begin{cases}p=x+y\\q=x-y\end{cases}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}$

$\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}-\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial x\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}\right)=\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}\left(\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}\right)\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}\left(\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}\right)\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial p^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial p\partial q}-\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial p\partial q}-\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial q^2}=\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial p^2}-\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial q^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial p^2}-\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial q^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}+\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}-\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial q}\right)$

$\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial p^2}-\dfrac{\partial^2I}{\partial q^2}=\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial p}$

Similar to [Can I combine the wave and heat equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290147)